# Unknown Duplicate card

Tags: android, firebase

When I remove card from recycleview adapter in firebase,  databasereference .removeValue method card is removed but remaining value gets temporary duplicate i.e everything become twice when i reOpen app everything normal

Comment: Hey beast98, maybe you could share some code and output so someone can pinpoint the exact problem?

Comment: Please add the code that you are using and the entire error that you get. Please also responde with @.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are not deleting well from UI and then when the app goes onResume it renders again values and then you have duplicates entries